# What's the name of this operation in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

whats the name of below operation in Pandas?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x=np.linspace(10,15,64)
y=np.random.permutation(64)

z=x[y]
```

ndarray "x" is (I assume) shuffled using ndarray "y" and then result ndarray is assigned to "z".

What is the name of this operation? I can't find it in Pandas documentation.

Thanks,
Pawel

Comment: It is called [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: No pandas methods are being used here. Only numpy operations.

Answer (score 0):

This is called **indexing**, both in Pandas and NumPy

---

This code is basically shuffling an array using an array of indices. Using pandas you could shuffle a `Series` containing `x` using [`Series.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html), and specifying `frac=1` so the whole sample is shuffled:

```
s = pd.Series(x)
s.sample(frac=1)

52    14.126984
1     10.079365
41    13.253968
16    11.269841
29    12.301587
9     10.714286
37    12.936508
19    11.507937
15    11.190476
56    14.444444
0     10.000000
45    13.571429
34    12.698413
12    10.952381
....
```

---

If you want to use the existing `y`, you could `index` the `Series` using the [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) indexer:

```
s.iloc[y]

8     10.634921
53    14.206349
48    13.809524
43    13.412698
51    14.047619
21    11.666667
9     10.714286
29    12.301587
5     10.396825
61    14.841270
56    14.444444
39    13.095238
30    12.380952
...
```

Here are the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) on indexing with pandas.